# Is this proper use

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

I was watching the movie Man of Steel and in it is this passage:

*"There's only one way this ends Cal; either you die, or I do."*

Now this sounds wrong to me. There's *two* outcomes.

*"There's only on way this ends Cal; one of us dies."*

This I've heard before and as the beginning of the sentence suggest, only has *one* outcome.

My question is, is it still proper to say the original passage?

Comment: This is a silly question. Two potential outcomes doesn't mean two actual outcomes.

Comment: It's all a matter of point of view. For the speaker and for Cal, there are two crucially different possible outcomes: the speaker dies, or Cal dies. But from the buzzards' point of view there is only one meaningful outcome: somebody dies. Yum!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the *probability of an outcome* with *the actual outcome*.

If we assume it is true that only one person out of the two will be alive following the action that is about to take place, then there **will be** only *one outcome*, but -- provided that each of the individuals has a greater-than-zero chance of surviving -- there **are** *two **possible** outcomes*.

Comment: ... It's a shortened version of 'The only realistically feasible set of possible outcomes to this situation is two-membered:'. You can see why they use the shortened version, in spite of the departure from a strictly logical use of language.